# WSO2 API Manager ERROR_CODE = 101503, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error in Sender

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I configure the API Manager 1.7.0 on windows 7 64 Bits and try to deploy the sample wiki.

As the script didn't work in windows I did the procedure manually, as was described in the quick-start, in fact, the most simple sample showed in the quick-start doesn't work https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Quick+Start+Guide#QuickStartGuide-CreatinganAPI the problem is the same.

I was able to publish the API, even more, I tried to test the production end-point with the API Manager wizard, and the test worked.

But when I try to test the service through the API Manager URI, the API manager return the following message "**INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 101503, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error in Sender**"

I followed all steps, and I generated the susbcriptions and keys neeeded, even more, I tried with other security token, or with other kind of SLA, and the API manager gave me a correct message: token invalid, or token expired, or number of requests exceded, BUT when the request is good (token, etc.), the response is bad "**INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 101503, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error in Sender**"

Any idea to solve this issue, I was reviewing the log, and the unique trace is the trace indicated in this topic "**INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 101503, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error in Sender**"

Many thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

if you are getting  ERROR_CODE = 101503 means APIM manager is unable to connect to backend service.So please make sure you back end service is reachable or If your backend service need any Basic Auth you need to provide it

```
<property name="Proxy-Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic', base64Encode('userName:password'))" scope="transport"/>
```